# Express res.render stuck in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

Steps:
pull data from mongodb to populate a link on search page. Be able to click the link to take end user to the generic business page which is auto filled by mongodb. render the page with the JSON data from mongodb.

Issues:
res.render gets stuck in Infinite Loop (no error is thrown also)

I've tried adding an if statement so res.render would not render again, yet still stuck in a loop.

routes/business.js

```
router.get('/:business', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.business);
    Business.getBusinessByUrl(req.params.business, (err, business) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('business', {
            found: true,
            business_name: business.business_name,
            business_profile_image: business.business_profile_image,
            business_url: business.business_url
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

models/business.js

```
module.exports.getBusinessByUrl = function (businessUrl, callback) {
    const query = { business_url: businessUrl };
   Business.find(query, callback);
};
```

Here is what it looks like in the browser :
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWQh3.png)

Let me know if you need any other code.

Comment: Hey @Masson Curtis. Mind showing us what's happening underneath `getBusinessByUrl` func?

Comment: Yeah no problem one sec.

Comment: You really want to halt the server if the lookup fails for a single request? That's what `throw err` will do, might want to rethink that...

Comment: Why do you have `if (err) throw err;` instead of actual error handling?

Comment: What makes you think that re.render stuck in infinite loop ?

Comment: Thanks @PatrickRoberts. I did not know that. any suggestions on why the code is looping?

Comment: @YouneL in the console when I run with nodemon it reloads by itself until I manually stop the code.

Comment: Well it looks like the page loaded `/business/:business` provided a response. I think you're confusing client-side JavaScript with Node.js. The server isn't stuck in an infinite loop, your browser code is.

Comment: @Mason Curtis to be honest, I don't see anything that would cause infinite loop here. `.find` is just a singular request, so if that actually is happening, it has to either be on your `Business` module or at your express middleware.

Comment: @Patrick Roberts Yeah I wouldn't be surprised if I mixed them up I'm still new and learning. By browser code your talking about the handlebars template correct?

Comment: No, your handlebars template is being run on the server. If the problem is in your browser, your Node.js scripts are not the suspect in this case (and usually most of the time).

Comment: @PatrykCieszkowski I also did not see any reason for the infinite loop. I basically assumed by the output still can't pin point the problem though.

Comment: Also it seems that you have a problem in serving static files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while of searching I couldn't find anything helpful. Eventually I figured it out. It happened to be that when I had commented out the line `<div w3-include-html="file-included.html">` it stopped infinitely loading. A thank you too everyone who tried to help me.